# Tomcat webcontainer - how to access an ssl encrypted oracle database

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, encryption, oracle11g

We configured our Oracle 11g (v11.2.0) database to use SSL encryption (Oracle Advanced Security).
We did so following the instructions in the SSL with [Oracle JDBC Thin Driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf). Only encryption, no authentication, which is "Case 1" in the white paper.

Next, we developed a small test client to check if we can access the now encrypted database.
Here's a bit of the code:

```
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=our_host)"
      + "(PORT=2484))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=our_service_name)))";

System.out.println("set properties");
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("user", "system");
props.setProperty("password", "our_password");
props.setProperty("oracle.net.ssl_cipher_suites",
                    "(SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, "
                        + "SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,"
                        + "SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA)");

System.out.println("get connection");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
System.out.println("got a connection");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select sysdate from dual");
while (rs.next()) {
  System.out.println("result = "+rs.getString(1));
}
rs.close();
stmt.close();
con.close();
```

This works just fine and spits out the correct value. But alas is just a test client. Now we have to configure our Tomcat (v7.0.21) webcontainer so that our webapplication can access the now encrypted database.
Before the encryption, we used a `dataSource` in `{tomcat.home}/conf/context.xml` which looked like this:

```
<Context>
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<Resource name="our_name" auth="Container"
          driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" logAbandoned="true" maxActive="30"
          maxIdle="5" maxWait="1000" removeAbandoned="true"
          removeAbandonedTimeout="60" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@our_host:1521:our_sid"
          username="admin_user" password="admin_user" validationQuery="select sysdate from dual"
          testOnReturn="true" />
<!-- more Resources ... -->
</Context>
```

I fiddled around with a couple of setups I found in some posts on the internet (`<Connector>` e.g. in `server.xml` - see below -, changed the jdbc thin driver url etc.), but achieved nothing. I have no clue how to proceed or even how to debug this.

I uncommented and tested (unsuccessfully) the connector in `{tomcat.home}/conf/server.xml`:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           ciphers="SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA" />
```

We'd like to do it via .xml files as we did previously, so we don't need to ship a new release to our customer.

If you need more information, I'm happy to provide you with everything if you tell me how and where to find it.

Thank you for your time,

regards

René

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I figured it out...

- changes in server.xml were unnecessary (which makes sense considering
  we only encrypted our database - not client <-> webserver).
- changed the url in the Resource to a tnsnames-style format
- added the connectionProperties attribute in the Resource

  url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=our_host)(PORT=2484))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=our_service_name)))"
  connectionProperties="oracle.net.ssl_cipher_suites=SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA"

Comment: This post is hidden. You deleted this post 15 mins ago.
I am facing the similar kind of issue and I am getting java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset. This is happening after update to SSL 1.2 on Oracle RDS server 12.2.01. I have used ojdbc8.jar instead but not luck. I have asked the question in stack
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66372287/local-tomcat-is-not-starting-and-not-able-to-connect-to-oracle-rds-after-updatin
Any help is appreciated